# Crystal Reports: Creating a Unique Identifier

Tags: mysql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I am trying to attribute supplement sales to doctors. Ideally, our sales reps would code for this during checkout and the doctor would be represented in a field called 'provider code'. However, due to human error/ just not knowing who a patient's doctor is the sales reps will code the sale generically, and will code this as 'TEAM' under provider code.

When I run a report in crystal reports I have grouped the transactions by another field, 'Patient ID'. Although the sales are coded generically, based upon the Patient ID grouping it becomes fairly obvious as to which doctor vitamin sales should be attributed.

My problem has been how to write a report which recognizes those vitamin sales coded as 'TEAM' uniquely. I have tried to tackle the problem in a few ways but all have focused on trying to have the report recognize that being within a certain group (i.e. a group where a provider code other than 'TEAM' is present) acts as a unique identifier.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance for your time!

```
EDIT: Data Example
**214**
ProviderCode  PatientID  TxnCode  Amount
JLK           214        Cxxx     xxx.xx
TEAM          214        Vxxx     xxx.xx
```

So the report is grouped primarily by Patient ID. It seems intuitive that vitamin sales grouped next to a clinical code (which can only be attributed to a provided) should be attributed to that provider, in this particular case, JLK.

I want to have a field which summarizes the vitamin sales for each provider at our clinic.

Comment: you want to exclude the `TEAM` from the `Provider code` group? is this your requirement?

Comment: could you post some data as example?

Comment: Vitamin sales should be attributed to an individual provider. This would hopefully be done via the provider code. However, sometimes in the provider code field a generic identifier, 'TEAM', is used. I want to attribute those vitamin sales coded under to 'TEAM' to the proper provider. Working on posting some data for example!

Comment: will there be `patient ID` recorded for the `provider code` TEAM?